# Select - Yes or No

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

I am making a yes or no `comboBox` labeled "comboBox". In my Items property of my `yesnocomboBox`, I put first item as `Yes`, and second item as No.

When I let my user select Yes, it has to show visibility to other certain labels and TextBoxs. How do I code to do that?

So far I have this and it isn't working:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(yesnocomboBox.SelectedItem = "0"){

    }
}
```

Okay, I chose to use a checkbox instead. This is my code so far for when a user checks the checkbox:

```
    private void yestochappedlipsCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (yestochappedlipsCheckBox.Checked = chapstickbrandsListBox.Visible = true)

            (choosewhatyouwanttobuyLabel.Visible = true);
```

How do I make both of their visibilities to appear true?

Comment: is `yesnocombobox` different to `comboBox1`?

Comment: You would be better served with checkbox. Using dropdown will cause 2 clicks to select an option if you only want to have yes and No options.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void yestochappedlipsCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (yestochappedlipsCheckBox.Checked)
     {
        chapstickbrandsListBox.Visible = true;
        choosewhatyouwanttobuyLabel.Visible = true;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you said you were switching to a checkbox but to do it with a combo would be quite simple.  I think you are using an assignment op in your code instead of an equal compare.  Try the following by checking the index instead of the item.

Also, as good coding practice, keep your brackets consistent.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(yesnocomboBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        label1.Visible = true;
        otherItem.Visible = true;
        anotherItem.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: To answer the question above, I think the reason his event handler is comboBox1 and his "if" is checking yesnocomBox is because he renamed that control without renaming the event handler.  It would also be wise to keep the control name and event handler consistently named.

Answer (score 0):

If you're too serious to use that `comboBox` with `Yes` or `No` choices. make sure to set the `DropDownStyle = DropDownList`

```
bool? IsYes;
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        //IsYes = comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0;
        choosewhatyouwanttobuyLabel.Visible = comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0;
    }
    else
    {
        IsYes = null;
    }
}
```